# Find reference of item from array - swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, collections, iterable

is there a shorter version of the code below?
Also, when accessed with "for var", it is not append because it is "pass by value". Any suggestions?

```
struct Food {
    var fruits = [Fruit]()
    var category = "summer fruits"
}
struct Fruit {
    var name = ""
}

var foods = Food()

let fruit = Fruit()
fruit.name == "banana"

for var food in foods    {
    if food.category == "summer fruits" {
        food.fruits.append(fruit)
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I have edited

Comment: You can't iterate over `foods` it needs to conform to Sequence.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. As Frankenstein said, `for var food in foods` will produce a compiler error. `var category = String` will also not compile.

Comment: sorry, i misspelled can you look again?

Comment: You still haven't addressed the real issue. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Dude, of course this code is not what I want to use. What I want is to find the right item in that array by querying a value in an item in the array without using the "for" loop.

Comment: example c# linq : var food = foods.FindOrDefault(i=>i.category == "summer fruits" );

Comment: Instead of explaining yourself in the comments edit your question so it becomes clear what you want to achieve, right now all I get from the question is that you have some code that doesn’t work and you want a shorter version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var` with arrays is tricky because they still act like values when being passed around (you get a copy, not a reference).

```
var foods = [Food()]
var food = foods[0]
food.fruits.append(Fruit(name: "banana"))
```

This does not work if you want to modify the struct inside the `foods` array. As soon as you do `var food = foods[0]` you get a *mutable copy* of `foods[0]`. The same principle is what causes your example to not work. You are getting a mutable copy of each element in your for loop.

Don't think about it as modifying the struct inside the array, instead think about modifying the array itself. Arrays in Swift are also structs, so changing any element in the array should be thought of as changing the array itself.

```
foods[0].fruits.append(Fruit(name: "banana"))
```

There is nothing creating a copy of a value here. You modify the element of the array directly. To do this in a loop, you must use an index:

```
for i in 0..<foods.count {
    foods[i].fruits.append(...)
}
```

If you want to just modify the first element matching your criterion there is a method for finding a particular index

```
if let index = foods.firstIndex(where: { $0.category == "summer fruits" }) {
    foods[index].fruits.append(fruit)
}
```

---

On another note, your code would really benefit from avoiding `var` and instead using `let` as much as possible.

```
let fruit = Fruit(name: "banana")
```

is much shorter and clearer than your code, and also would help you avoid bugs like using `==` instead of `=` for assignment.